# Microsoft Flow - Iterate and parse XML file

Tags: xml, automation, power-automate

I am currently trying to iterate through a XML file and get the data using Microsoft Flow.

I cannot figure out how to iterate through multiple XML elements. Please see below example.

This is my XML data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
</ShipmentProfileReport>
  <ShipmentProfileReportItem>
    <JobOperator>John Doe</JobOperator>
     <Master>17231888581</Master>
  </ShipmentProfileReportItem>
  <ShipmentProfileReportItem>
    <JobOperator>Jane Doe</JobOperator>
    <Master>78423082032</Master>
  </ShipmentProfileReportItem>
</ShipmentProfileReport>
```

I wish to iterate through all `<ShipmentProfileReportItem>` items, and get:

`<JobOperator>`
`<Master>`

This is my flow:

[image]

**XML (ShipmentProfileReportItem):** 
`xpath(xml(outputs('XML_File')),'//ShipmentProfileReportItem')`

**Compose 2 (Inside foreach)**:
`xpath(xml(item()),'string(.)')`

This returns:

```
  John Doe
  17231888581
```

And

```
  JaneDoe
  78423082032
```

However above is just returned as above string. I want to update a sharepoint list. My question is: How can I access the lines seperately? For example:

```
xpath(xml(item("Master")),'string(.)')
xpath(xml(item("JobOperator")),'string(.)')
```

Answer (score 2):

it's done like this inside the each loop:

```
xpath(item(),'string(ShipmentProfileReportItem/JobOperator)')
```

I never thought I'd do this, but read up about xpath on [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp)

Comment: having same issue can you help https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/305125/get-value-from-http-response-xml-and-pass-it-as-a-field-in-next-http-request-fie